# Sharepoint RSS feed description fields as elements

Tags: sharepoint, rss

This is my first time working with RSS but I am fluent with XML/XSL.  I have a RSS feed that I am pulling from a list in Sharepoint.  The sample XML is below.
The RSS description element parses the various columns (Body, Expires, Attachments) that are in the Sharepoint list automatically.  I know that from the list I can control which fields are included in the description, but this is not what I am looking to do.

**Is there any way to force the fields to come through in an XML element format instead of the CDATA that converted to HTML?**  For example, I may want to check a priority field and if it is important when applying the XSL I would bold red it or something.  Since this is in the HTML/CDATA format it makes it messy to parse that field.

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Announcements</title>
    <link>http://somewebsite/Announcements/Current.aspx</link>
    <description>RSS feed for the Announcements list.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Aug 2009 17:31:01 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Windows SharePoint Services V3 RSS Generator</generator>
    <ttl>1</ttl>
    <image>
      <title>Announcements</title>
      <url>/_layouts/images/homepage.gif</url>
      <link>http://somewebsite/Announcements/Current.aspx</link>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>Woohoo a post! </title>
      <link>http://somewebsite/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=36</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[<div><b>Body:</b> <div>
<div>The attached email was sent from chairman and CEO on Tuesday March 3, 2009.</div>
<div></div></div></div>
<div><b>Expires:</b> 7/30/2009</div>
<div><b>Attachments:</b> <a href="http://somewebsite/Woohoo.htm">http://somewebsite/Woohoo.htm</a><br><a href=""></a></div>
]]>
      </description>
      <author>Me, Myself and I</author>
      <pubDate>Thu, 16 Jul 2009 18:38:32 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://somewebsite/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=69</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [RSSBus SharePoint Web Part](http://www.rssbus.com/products/sharepoint/). This lets you format the SharePoint RSS feeds using templates so you can get just the output you want. It's not open source or free however there is a trial that may assist you.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the info but do to restrictions I have to use the native web parts.  I noticed that some lists product data in different ways than others.  For example an RSS for a BLOG is different than an RSS for a Custom List.  Any way, I'm working with what I have for now and displaying the ugly CDATA.  Just didn't want to leave this unresponded

Comment: @Jay: As is often true with SharePoint, the foundation is there but it often needs to be extended to obtain desired results!